# How to calculate and update average value in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I want to update `avg` field every time when updating `star`.

```
{
  _id : "001",
  star: {
    avg: 2.6
    count: 3,
    _1: 1,
    _2: 0,
    _3: 1,
    _4: 1,
    _5: 0,
  }
}
```

How can I update `avg` field ?

```
// `avg` should update to number 2 where { count: 2, _1: 1, _3: 1 }
db.Collection.updateOne({_id:"001"},{ $inc:{ "star._4": -1 , "star.count": -1 }})

// `avg` should update to number 3.5 where { count: 2, _4: 1, _3: 1 }
db.Collection.updateOne({_id:"001"},{ $inc:{ "star._1": -1 , "star._4": 1 }})
```

Comment: You can use [Update with Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/index.html) feature to get your average calculation/update also when a field is modified.

Comment: what is the `avg` of? it's not of the `_1`..`_5` keys.

Comment: @TomSlabbaert . `_1..._5` is star count of 1-5.`{ _5 : 3 } ` so if  _5 * 3. where 5 is Category and 3 is number of _5 stars